# Quitting master degree MBA

Tags: masters, quitting

I am planning to quit my master degree ( I have completed 14 of 20 months) because I dont feel it will be helpful in my career, I also dont like to do a final Business model plan (which is huge around 180 pages) to get the degree (it must have financial evaluation and more stuff that are not related to my carreer, I studied Informatic engineer by the way).

I am struggling with continuing it, I already have my Engineer degree, I know the world it is more competitive but it doesnt mean that every employee must have a master degree in order to suceed.

I dont regret the time invested, I prefer studying and get a specialization program in my career field rather than a degree in something I wont work and invest more money and time just because "I must finish what I started" and then dont take advantage of it.

Tell me your opinions please

Comment: There is no question here and soliciting opinions is also not on topic.

Comment: What is your specific uncertainty here?  What is it that you want to know?  If you are just here to unburden yourself to the internet... this is not the place for that.

Answer (score 1):

Even if an MBA is of no benefit to you and not relevant to a job you're seeking, finishing it is always going to look better on your resume/CV than not finishing it.

Answer (score 0):

MBA are helpful only because of the network you build during your final assignment.

The intrinsic value of a completed MBA is close to 0.

However, in the late stage of your career, people would expect you to have an MBA, to offer you higher managment role in complex, large corporate environments.

Where do you want to be in 20 years? the indivdual consultant paid 50-500$ per hour, or the high order manager in a big company?